# How can I remove duplicate values by looking at other column values in the data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, row, identity-column

There are two columns with opposite values of item1 and item2 columns, and the order of the columns is random.

I want to find and remove data with the same values in columns item1 and item2.

like this...

[image]

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `base`

```r
df <- structure(list(Item1 = c("A", "C", "B", "D", "E", "F"), 
                     Item2 = c("B", "D", "A", "C", "F", "E"), 
                     Result = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.6)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

fltr <- !duplicated(apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "")))

df[fltr, ]
#>   Item1 Item2 Result
#> 1     A     B    0.5
#> 2     C     D    0.1
#> 5     E     F    0.7
#> 6     F     E    0.6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I am taking a more generalised case

```
dput(df)

df <- structure(list(Item1 = c("A", "C", "B", "D", "E", "F"), Item2 = c("B", 
"D", "A", "C", "F", "E"), Result = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 
0.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

> df
  Item1 Item2 Result
1     A     B    0.5
2     C     D    0.1
3     B     A    0.5
4     D     C    0.1
5     E     F    0.7
6     F     E    0.6
```

## Code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c("Item1", "Item2")) %>%
  group_by(Result, value) %>%
  slice_head() %>%
  group_by(Result) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Result, names_from = name, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Result [4]
  Result Item1 Item2
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1    0.1 C     D    
2    0.5 A     B    
3    0.6 F     E    
4    0.7 E     F
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pmin` and `pmax` to sort the values alphabetically and select the unique rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  transmute(Item_1 = pmin(Item1, Item2), 
            Item_2 = pmax(Item1, Item2), 
            Result) %>%
  distinct()

#  Item_1 Item_2 Result
#1      A      B    0.5
#2      C      D    0.1
```

---

In base R :

```
unique(transform(df, Item1 = pmin(Item1, Item2), 
                     Item2 = pmax(Item1, Item2)))
```

Comment: Good usage of parallel minima/maxima.  But I think these may change the order of columns where duplicate/mirror images aren't found! Please check

Comment: Yes that is true but I am not sure 1) if such situation exists. 2) If it exists what OP wants to do in that case (since `A->B` was selected over `B->A`). Looking at the example my guess is it does not matter if an item is classified as `item1` or `item2` but I maybe wrong.

Comment: Yes agreed.  But I normally use SO for my R/Tableau learning therefore, I generalized the situation that may occur.  Moreover, I was specifically looking for your fantastic way of solving this problem, that's why I asked.  Hope you would take it positively.  Thanks

Comment: @AnilGoyal Hey no issue in pointing out any mistake/assumptions that you find in my answer to improve the quality of the post.